# Запятая перед КАК нужна?

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая перед "как": «Меню как в городском ресторане».

Answer (score 1):

Вот не надо ничего менять и подставлять, так как при этом меняется структура и грамматика предложения. Соответственно, это уже другое предложение со своими знаками.

Сравнительный оборот обособляется или не обособляется в зависимости от расстановки ударения в **конкретном предложении и в конкретном тексте**.

Например:

(1) *Здесь красИво, **меню как в городском ресторАне**.*

(2) *Здесь красиво, уютно, удобная мебель. **МенЮ, как в городском ресторане**.*

Оборот обособляется, если ставим ударение на слове ***меню***.

Пример с обособлением из литературы: *Богатство вестибюля, ресторанного зала, много богатых американцев и англичан. **Меню, как будто нет войны**.*  [И. А. Бунин. Дневники (1940-1953)]

Answer (score 0):

Нужна — это сравнение, так как по смыслу можно подставить слово "такое":
*Меню такое, как в городском ресторане.*

Сравнение требует постановки знаков препинания. Оборот является сравнительным, если по смыслу слово "как" можно заменить на "как будто" или "как и":
*Меню, как будто в городском ресторане.* || Подходит.
*Меню, как и в городском ресторане.*

Answer (score 0):

Конструкция с союзом «как» может быть сказуемым:

Весь остров как узор живого храма;
Всё как на картинках: и горы, и лес, и вода; 
Волосы у девочки как солома;
Вся жизнь его как светлый праздник; 
Душонка у тебя как у зайца; 
На войне как на войне; 
Она ему как мать родная;

Поэтому "Меню как в городском ресторане".